# PackageManagement module loading is shown in verbose output from advanced funtions

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell module with advanced function. When I call this function in verbose mode, PackageManagement module loading verbose output is also shown at the start. Is there a way I can suppress it and limit to verbose output from only the function, I have created.

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1\PackageManagement.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1\PackageManagement.format.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1\Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.dll'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Find-Package'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Get-Package'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Get-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Get-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Install-Package'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Import-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Find-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Install-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Register-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Save-Package'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Set-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Uninstall-Package'.
VERBOSE: Exporting cmdlet 'Unregister-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Find-Package'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Find-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-Package'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Import-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Install-Package'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Install-PackageProvider'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Register-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Save-Package'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Set-PackageSource'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Uninstall-Package'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Unregister-PackageSource'.
```

Comment: -Verbose:$false ?

Comment: have you tried explicitly loading the module before you try to use the cmdlet? my understanding is that the 1st call to a module component will load the module ... so perhaps loading the module in advance would prevent the `-Verbose` switch from being seen by the module loader.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes its happening on the first run of the console session. If I call the same function again PackageManagement verbose output goes away. If I import that module explicitly before calling the function then also the additional verbose output goes away. Further what I observed is PackageManagement is not loaded by default. Any idea why its happening? As its under 'C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\' path it should be loaded by default. Right?

Comment: i THINK what is happening is that - when the module it NOT already loaded - calling one of the cmdlets that requires that module loads the module _and passes the `-Verbose` parameter to the module_. if that is what is happening, then the only workarounds i can think of are [A] don't use the `-Verbose` parameter [*grin*] OR [B] explicitly load the module before you call on any of its cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

As @guiwhatsthat said, You have to append the `-Verbose:$false` parameter to the `Import-Module` call :

```
Import-Module -Name ModuleName -Verbose:$false
```